# jsTree state plugin reloads page continually

Tags: jstree

I'm using jsTree as a navigation menu, and after clicking any of the links the page reloads over and over... I've searched all day for an answer to this and would very much appreciate a hand.

```
        $('#NavTreeContainer').jstree({
        'core': {
            'themes': {
                'name': 'default',
                'responsive': true,
                'stripes': true,
                'dots': true,
                'icons': false
            }
        },
        'state' : { 'key' : 'navTree' },
        'plugins' : [ 'state' ]
    }).on('select_node.jstree', function(e, data) {
        document.location = data.instance.get_node(data.node, true).children('a').attr('href');
    });
    $('#ExpandAllNavTreeButton').click(function() {
        $('#NavTreeContainer').jstree('open_all');
    });
    $('#CollapseAllNavTreeButton').click(function() {
        $('#NavTreeContainer').jstree('close_all');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this functionality working by only binding the select node event after the tree state has been restored;

```
    $('#jstree_id').jstree({
        "state": { "key": "jstree_id" },
        "plugins": ["state"]
    }).on('restore_state.jstree', function () {
        $('#jstree_id').on('select_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
                var href = data.node.a_attr.href;
                document.location.href = href;
        });
    });
```

If you already solved this I hope it helps someone else.